# Specific data structure in R (number and list as one row)

Tags: r, list

I need to have this data structure in R:

1. column = number (ID)
2. column = list of N numeric values

How to do this? I tried a lot of solutions, but I either have a problem with "replacement has 2 rows, data has 1" or it does not create a list as a column.

I believe this is possible.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: It is possible, but that doesn't mean that it is to be done `data.frame(id=1:3, y=list(1,2,3,4))`

Comment: Have you googled for an R tutorial ?  You should also show what you tried.

Comment: It's better to do `lst = list(1,2,3); names(lst) <- ids`

Comment: @PierreLafortune hmm, that looks good, but how to create it in a for loop?

@steveb sure, I have completed several R tutorials
one of my solutions were: 
`data_frame <- data.frame("ID" = numeric(), "values" = NULL)
  data_frame[i , 1] <- ID
  while (cond) {
    data_frame[i, 2] <- c(data_frame[i, 2], other_data$values[j])
}`

Comment: without any type of data I'm not exactly sure what you need. but here is something I used to address the problem: `taudat1=data.frame(matrix(nrow=20001))
for (i in 1:(length(alldat_abs)-1))
{
  if (max(alldat_abs[1:30000,i])>peakThreshold)
  {
    start=which.max(alldat_abs[1:30000,i])
    taudat1=cbind(taudat1,as.data.frame((alldat_abs[start:(start+20000),i])))
  }
  else {taudat1=cbind(taudat1,as.data.frame(matrix(0,nrow = 20001,ncol=1)))}
}`

This is direct from my code so replace the variable names but the idea is to use cbind in the for loop and bind the current data with the new data.

Comment: I need to create a data matrix, where one column will have N (100) numeric values, which I need to cluster (with kmeans()) later... I suppose kmeans() is capable of doing that, you know, cluster by not just one value, but N

Comment: @JustinBrousseau Do you understand my plans now? I don't need this data structure indeed, if there is a way how to get those data into clustering function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was to create a data matrix where each column had its own value.